# Algebra: sums of rows and columns given, find elements

Tags: linear-algebra

I stumbled upon the following problem, which got me confused:
\begin{array}[x]{3}
~ & y_1 & y_2\\
z_1 & x_{11} & x_{12} \\
z_2 & x_{21} & x_{22} \\
\end{array}

$z_1$ and $z_2$ are the sums of the respective rows, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the sums of the respective columns, eg. $z_1 = x_{11} + x_{12}$, $y_1 = x_{11} + x_{21}$, and so forth. If the values of $z_1, z_2, y_1, y_2$ are given, how can I get the x-values?

Thank you for rectifying comments!

Comment: :whats x-values?

Comment: Solve the system of linear equations maybe? :)

Comment: +1, this is what the mathemagicians used! There used to be number of cards with table of numbers in each one, and just by telling them which cards have your number they would tell you the number!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have enough data to do so.  The responses showing four equations in four unknowns miss the dependency of the equations.  If we add the $z$ equations we get the same combination of $x$'s as if we add the $y$ equations.  For a specific example, you can't tell $\begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1 \end {pmatrix}$ from $\begin {pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end {pmatrix}$ as  $y_1=y_2=z_1=z_2=1$ in both cases

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have four equations:

$y_1 = x_{11} + x_{21}$

$y_2 = x_{12} + x_{22}$

$z_1 = x_{11} + x_{12}$

$z_2 = x_{21} + x_{22}$

With $z$, $y$ constant, you can solve for any given $x$, and then use that to solve for its neighbor.